# 他のアプリが開かれたことを検知することは可能ですか？

Tags: swift, ios, objective-c, xcode

制作中のアプリ（以下マイアプリ）で

1. マイアプリが閉じられたとき
2. マイアプリ以外のアプリが開かれたとき

にローカル通知の予約を入れたいと考えています。

１の閉じられたときの通知予約は`applicationDidEnterBackground`の中で行い、スリープボタンとホームボタンのどちらが押下されたか？という判定は[こちらの質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595928/differentiate-between-screen-lock-and-home-button-press-on-ios7)を参考に実装しました。無事にホームボタンで閉じられた時にのみ通知の予約を設定することができました。

今回ご質問させていただきたいのは２のほうで、マイアプリ以外が開かれたということを、どうにかして察知できないかと考えています。
「マイアプリ以外が開かれた」ことを察知するタイミングはリアルタイムでなく、次回マイアプリが開かれたとき（`applicationWillEnterForeground`が呼ばれるときなど）で構いません。

何かしら方法はありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOSでは自分のアプリケーション以外の状態を知ることはできません。

Comment: 具体的にはForestというスマホ依存解消アプリで実現されているようなことなのですが、このアプリはタイマーをセットしてセットしたスマホを閉じたままにしいると

Comment: Forestを使ってみましたが、単にバックグラウンドに移ったタイミングで処理をしてるだけで、他のアプリを使ったかどうかなどは関係ないように見えます。

Comment: Forestでタイマースタート -> スリープボタンでクローズ -> ロック画面のウィジェットもしくはカメラから入ってForestの画面を経由せず他のアプリを起動 -> 他のアプリを閉じてホームアイコンからForestを起動 -> これでForestのタイマーが失敗判定され木が枯れてしまいます。バックグラウンドに入るタイミングだけで処理をしているのであれば、スリープボタン押下時しか処理をするタイミングがないので、他のアプリを経由してからForestを開いたということは察知できず、失敗判定はできないと思うのですがどうやって判定しているのでしょうか。なお他アプリには10秒程度は滞在してからForestを開かないと失敗判定にはなりません。

Comment: 他のアプリのことが察知できないのであれば、「マイアプリ画面が開かれていない」、「ホーム画面に戻った」、「ホームアイコンから起動された」などを判定できる方法があればなんとかなりそうなのですが、、

Comment: @Takeshi 同じようにやってみましたが、「他のアプリを開いた」という判定ではなく、単に「自分のアプリを閉じた＋時間経過」で判定しているように見えます。現に他のアプリを開いてもすぐForestに戻って来れば失敗にはならないですよね？

Comment: iPhoneがスリープ中は進まず、アプリがバックグラウンドにある間は進む時間計測のやり方があるということでしょうか？それなら私のやりたいことも実現できそうです。調べてみます。ありがとうございます！

Comment: [NSProcessInfoのsystemUptime](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/9558/iphone%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E6%99%82%E9%96%93%E7%AB%AF%E6%9C%AB%E3%81%8C%E3%82%B9%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E6%99%82%E9%96%93%E3%82%92%E8%A8%88%E6%B8%AC%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)システムの起動時間の差を利用するという方法にたどり着いたのですが、これですとロック画面での起動時間も含まれてしまうためうまくいきませんでした。「自分のアプリを閉じた＋時間経過」をはかる方法は他にあるのでしょうか？

Comment: ようやくおっしゃってる意味がわかりました。木が枯れる条件は、「1. アプリケーションを起動中にホームボタンを押してホーム画面に戻る」「2. スリープボタンで画面をロック、その後ウィジェットやカメラなどを経由して自分のアプリに戻らずに別のアプリまたはホーム画面を表示する」と２つあって、「3. 画面をロックしただけ」では条件を満たさないが、2と3を区別できない、ということですね。これは難しいですけど、参考のリンクにあるように`DarwinNotifyCenter`を使うなら`"com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete"`以外に`"com.apple.springboard.lockstate"`というものがあり、これはロックの状態が変わる（ロック、非ロック）たびに通知が来るのでそれと組み合わせて判断できるのではないでしょうか？つまり、`"com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete"`だけならロック中なのでまだ枯れない（3の状態）、その後に`"com.apple.springboard.lockstate"`が呼ばれてフォアグラウンドにならなければ2ということになると思います。

Comment: 私の求めていたのはずばり"com‌​.apple.springboard.l‌​ockstate"でした。なんとか希望どおりの実装ができました。実装には以下のリンクを参考にしました。[「画面のロック、アンロックを検知する方法」](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/nosfilter/20140704/1404435763)   [「Is there a way to check if the iOS device is locked/unlocked?」](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229955/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-the-ios-device-is-locked-unlocked)ありがとうございました。